# Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved

Tags: c++, excel, automation, runtime, runtime-error

I am trying to compile example of Excel automation access from C++ code and I get the following error: "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

I've already found and read tons of info about this error in internet, but still can't get the point what exactly should I fix in my code to make it work. Please review the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL" no_implementation rename("RGB", "ExclRGB") rename("DocumentProperties", "ExclDocumentProperties") rename("SearchPath", "ExclSearchPath")
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB" no_implementation
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" rename("DialogBox", "ExclDialogBox") rename("RGB", "ExclRGB") rename("CopyFile", "ExclCopyFile") rename("ReplaceText", "ExclReplaceText")

BOOL EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM)
{
   WCHAR szClassName[64];
   if(GetClassNameW(hwnd, szClassName, 64))
   {
      if(_wcsicmp(szClassName, L"EXCEL7") == 0)
      {
         //Get AccessibleObject
         Excel::Window* pWindow = NULL;
         HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, __uuidof(Excel::Window), (void**)&pWindow);
         if(hr == S_OK)
         {
            //Excel object is now in pWindow pointer, from this you can obtain the document or application
            Excel::_Application* pApp = NULL;
            pApp = pWindow->GetApplication();
            pWindow->Release();
         }
         return false;     // Stops enumerating through children
      }
   }
   return true;
}

int main( int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    //The main window in Microsoft Excel has a class name of XLMAIN
    HWND excelWindow = FindWindow(L"XLMAIN", NULL);
    //Use the EnumChildWindows function to iterate through all child windows until we find _WwG
    EnumChildWindows(excelWindow, (WNDENUMPROC) EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It became clear that MS Visual Studio uses __cdecl calling convention while EnumChildWindows() uses __stdcall. This mismatch leads to an error. The question is what should be changed in code or IDE to eliminate this error?

Comment: Nothing needs to be changed. Just add the CALLBACK macro to your function definition as described [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you are good to go. The macro sets up the proper calling convention for you so you don't need to worry about what it actually is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
EnumChildWindows(..., (WNDENUMPROC) EnumChildProc, ...);
```

That (WNDENUMPROC) cast just stopped the compiler from telling you that you were doing it wrong.  It didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Fix:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM)
{
    // etc..
}
```

Note the added CALLBACK macro, it selects the required __stdcall calling convention for the callback.  Without it, it defaults to __cdecl, another calling convention that requires the caller to cleanup the stack after the call.  Which won't happen and thus imbalances the stack.

The proper callback signature is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
BOOL EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM)
```

Needs to be:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM)
```